# mi consulta en sql no reconoce el parametro que le envio desde javascript

Tags: php, javascript, sql, json

buenas tardes programadores tengo una duda y espero me ayuden 
estoy desarrollando un sistema en javascript y php y sqlserver, el problema es el siguiente 
esta es la parte de php en la cual el envio el parametro de javascript que es "USU"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y la mando a llamar con un metodo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en otra pagina de php tengo un boton que hace lo siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

espero me puedan ayudar 
lo principal que quiero hacer esque en javascript mando a llamar a un elemento de la pantalla que es usu y si lo jala con el .innerhtml pero una vez teniendolo en javascript quiero mandarlo a un php para poder hacer una inserción en la base de datos espero su ayuda gracias, o si conocen otro metodo enviar la viable usu de javascript a php se los agradeceria

**si me pueden ayudar a que el dato usu que jale a javascript desde html ahora pueda tomarlo en una consulta desde php gracias**

Comment: la función tiene el nombre us y en el boton la llaman como usu

Comment: muchas gracias si ya correji el problema pero sigo sin poder hacer la insersion ala base de datos seguire buscando

Comment: si estas usando jquery has un nomas remplaza el getJSON por post y de lado del servidor pon $_POST["usu"] en ves del $_GET

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Por favor en lugar de imágenes pon el texto con el código, de ese modo es más fácil poder leer la pregunta, revisar el código o reutilizarlo para hacer pruebas.  Aparte de lo que ya te han dicho, el código PHP no es coherente en el sentido de que la petición que mandas desde Javascript espera un JSON de respuesta. Tú envías un JSON solamente si el código funciona bien, pero si funciona mal, haces un `echo "falla";` deberías recoger una u otra posibilidad en una variable e imprimirla al final con `json_encode` para que el código sea coherente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

llamas a una funcion usu y el relidad dice us creo que ese es tu problema

```
 <input type="button" name="" value="enviar" onclick="usu()"/>
```

tienes un problema en esta linea la coma al final non va

```
$sql= "INSERT INTO ventas_Cuentas(cuenta,folio,cliente)VALUES(999,292,'.$usu.',)";
```

deberia ser asi

```
$sql= "INSERT INTO ventas_Cuentas(cuenta,folio,cliente)VALUES(999,292,'.$usu.')";
```

Comment: muchas gracias si ya correji el problema pero sigo sin poder hacer la insersion ala base de datos seguire buscando

Comment: mira mi edicion el problema esta al final de tu query

Comment: mira mi edicion el problema esta en tu query

Comment: gracias ya lo cambie ya no tengo el mismo error ahora tengo otro pero ya no es el mismo gracias seguiré viendo